# Change option value based on it's current value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<select class="file_image_type" name="file_image_type">
        <option>Gallery</option>
        <option>Feature</option>
        <option>Thumbnail</option>
    </select>
```

This is generated dynamically and is repeated for each item. Since there can only be one Feature image, I want to reset the option value of any labeled as "Feature" whenever a new image is selected as being a "Feature".

I've tried this jQuery but it doesn't seem to be responding:

```
current.find(".file_image_type option[value='Feature']").val("Gallery");
```

I'm able to set the image as Feature just fine using this:

```
current.find(".file_image_type").val("Feature");
```

Comment: your `option` elements don't have `value` attributes, so you can't select them by it

Comment: What is "current" in the context of your javascript?

Comment: For the attribute selector to work, the elements must have the attribute.

Comment: You could change markup like `<option>Gallery</option>` to be `<option value="Gallery">Gallery</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People, people, you do not need to select the `option`s directly in jQuery. I can't believe how many times I see this mistake.

```
$('.file_image_type').change(function() {  
    $('.file_image_type').not(this).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() === 'Feature') {
            $this.val('Gallery');
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

"Gallery" is not the `val()`, it's the `text()`.

Comment: It is the text of the option, but you never need to select that far in unless you are actually changing the contents of the options.